# Как реализовать появление/скрытие блоков при прокрутке вверх-вниз?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет!

Есть такой блок :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копать

```js
function showingQuotes() {
  var parent = $('.top-quotes-block');
  var block_1,
    block_2,
    block_3;

  if ($('.first-quote').length) {
    block_1 = $('.first-quote')
  }
  if ($('.second-quote').length) {
    block_2 = $('.second-quote')
  }
  if ($('.third-quote').length) {
    block_3 = $('.third-quote')
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ((parent.offset().top < ($(document).scrollTop() + 60 + $(window).height() / 2)) &&
      ((parent.offset().top + parent.height()) > ($(document).scrollTop() + 60 + $(window).height() / 2))
    ) {
      propperOrder();
    }

  });

  function propperOrder() {
    block_1.animateCss('fadeIn', function() {
      block_1.addClass('animated fadeIn');
      $(window).ready(function() {
        $(this).one('scroll', function() {
          block_1.animateCss('fadeOut', function() {
            block_1.addClass('animated fadeOut').removeClass('fadeIn');
          });
          block_2.animateCss('fadeIn', function() {
            block_2.addClass('animated fadeIn');
            $(window).ready(function() {
              $(this).one('scroll', function() {
                block_3.animateCss('fadeIn', function() {
                  block_3.addClass('animated fadeIn');
                });
                block_2.animateCss('fadeOut', function() {
                  block_2.addClass('animated fadeOut').removeClass('fadeIn');
                });
              })
            })
          });
        })
      })
    })
  }

}
```

```css
.top-quotes-block .flex-row {
   height: 200px;
   position: static;
}
    
.top-quotes-block .fullwidth-content {
position: relative;
    }
    
    .top-quotes-block .quote {
     opacity: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin: 0;
     min-width: 200px;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


<p>В нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копатьВ нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копатьВ нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копать</p>

<div class="fullwidth-section text-light top-quotes-block parallax-section" data-parallax-image="img/quote_pic.jpg">
  <div class="fullwidth-content wrapper-small align-center">
    <div class="nav-light" data-dots="true">
      <div class="flex-row">
        <blockquote class="quote first-quote">
          He who controls the past controls the future. He who controls the present controls the past.
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote class="quote second-quote">
          Law is on the side of those with the deepest pockets and with friends in the highest places
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote class="quote third-quote">
          Third quote Third quote Third quote Third quote Third quote Third quote Third quote Third quote
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

   

 <p>В нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
    При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
    Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копатьВ нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
    При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
    Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копатьВ нем еще есть 2 цитаты. Задача такая :
    При скроле при первом появлении появляется первая цитата, потом при тригере прокрутки вторая, еще раз при тригире третья. Если скролим снизу вверх, то получается начием с третьей цитаты.
    Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это можно сделать или куда копать</p>
```

Comment: а сам чего сделал?  что именно не получается?

Comment: посмотри вот тут...  принцип тот же  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732884/Как-сделать-чтобы-элементы-при-прокрутке-меняли-margin-left-или-подобное-если-е/732899#732899

Comment: @Air интересная штука получилась )

Comment: @Air Добавил код, глянь плиз. У меня не получается пустить по новой. Например, показал все три блока, а когда юзер скроллит обратно - как откатить назад? Показать 3-2-1 ?

Comment: @Даниил, ну да...  Довести до ума и будет красота...)

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov, а стили где?

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov, я с удовольствием, только  у  меня вопрос...  Почему ты не положение элементов  определяешь а от скрола окна отталкиваешься?

Comment: @Air Хз,  добавил все библиотеки, а оно не работает.
Ну, если положения и актуальный скролл

Comment: @Air так что, подсобишь? В твоём коде, который ты скинул - есть идеи. почему не может не работать items.addEventListener('scroll') ?

Comment: минутку, я щас....

Comment: @Air ок, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь ты меня не зря ждал, начал делать и даже не сказал, что не дружу с JQ...
Ну если не я, то другие точно помогут... Я люблю чистый JS

```js
var quote = document.getElementsByClassName('quote');
quote[0].classList.add('quoteActive');

for (let i = 0; i < quote.length; i++) {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop <= 100) {
      quote[i].classList.remove('quoteActive');
      quote[0].classList.add('quoteActive');

    } else if (scrollTop <= 200) {
      quote[i].classList.remove('quoteActive');
      quote[1].classList.add('quoteActive');

    } else if (scrollTop <= 300) {
      quote[i].classList.remove('quoteActive');
      quote[2].classList.add('quoteActive');

    }


  })
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

.quote {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: gray;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.quote.quoteActive {
  position: sticky;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="quote first-quote">
  111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
</blockquote>
<blockquote class="quote second-quote">
  22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
</blockquote>
<blockquote class="quote third-quote">
  3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Та мне уже хоть на ассамблере :) Сек, проверю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709427/как-динамический-во-время-scroll-определить-текущее-местоположение-элемента-по-о

Comment: Так, а если они все на одном оффсете?

Comment: Буквально лежат друг на друге абсолютом

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov, поиграй с условием...  с марджинами.. с позициями, я же не знаю как у тебя и что))

Comment: тут главное есть условие, которое ты можешь под себя поделать...   ты уже видишь принцип работы...

Comment: та я понимаю, не первый день над задачей сижу. Хорошо, можеть подсказать, как создать условие на увеличение уменьшение? Это бы помогло. Например, по скроллу в блоке - что значение идет от 0 до x и от x к 0?

Comment: есть event по прокрутке колеса мыши.. не путай со scroll-ом... есть scroll...  тут тот же принцип можешь использовать.. добавлять классы удалять...  или определять длину scroll-ла и уже в условии расширять сужать... в зависимости от длинны scroll-ла...  можно по разному... Зависит от конкретной задачи

Comment: Ну, у меня вот конкретная задача...Например, 100 пикселей прокрутили вниз - скрыли 1ю показали вторую. Еще 100 вниз - 2ю скрыли, показали третбю. Потом если крутим ВВЕРХ 100 пикселей, то скрываем 3 и показываем второую.

Comment: а первая изначально не скрыта я так понимаю?

Comment: Да. Первая показана всегда. Мы доскролили до родителя - скрыли первую, показали вторую. Проскролили 100 пикселей - скрыли вторую, показали третью. Если начинаем скроллить вверх, то показываем вторую, скрываем третью. Проскролили 100 пикселей, скрыли 2ю показали первую

Comment: Понимаю, прошу многого но был бы тебе очень благодарен за решение

Comment: Так, я тебя правильно понял?

Comment: Да, но только элементы то с абсолютом...Они на одном месте, друг на друге лежат. Скорее всего решение должно быть на коллбэках...

Comment: Вот ты чего хотел...? ))))

Comment: Куда тебе миллион биткоинов скидывать?)
Спасибо :)Немного рифтану и будет бомба

Comment: не надо)))  обойдусь принятым ответом))))))

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!